# Logging fatal errors

Tags: php

I have a simple logging class to write log messages into a log file.

```
class Logger {
   // write a custom message to the log file
   public static function log($msg) {
       $hndl = fopen('log.log');
       fwrite($hndl, $msg);
       fclose($hndl);
   }

   // write errors to log file
   public static err_callback($eno, $emsg) {
       Logger::log($msg);
       return false;
   }

   // write fatal errors to log file
   public static ftl_callback() {
       $error = error_get_last();

       if ($error['type'] == E_ERROR) {
           Logger::log($error['message']);
       }
   }
}
```

I register the err_callback and ftl_callback functions to write PHP errors to the log file as follows:

```
register_shutdown_function('Logger::ftl_callback');
set_error_handler('Logger::err_callback');
```

When calling Logger::log() directly or when a non-fatal error occures then logging works fine, however on fatal errors I receive the following error:

> Warning: fopen(log.log): failed to open stream: Permission denied in E:_websites\c\phpSource\Logger.php on line 181

Why do I receive "Permission denied" error when fatal error occures? Is it an issue with PHP or a configuration issue? If it is PHP then is there a workaround for it?

Environment:
PHP 5.3.8
IIS 6.1
Windows 7

All help appreciated.

Comment: $hndl = fopen('log.log); should be $hndl = fopen('log.log');

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is happening because, while dying, the php changes the current directory, causing your code to save the file in the wrong place. Try configuring the absolute path beforehand, using `realpath`. Example:

```
public static set_target_file($file) {
    self::$file = realpath($file);
}
```

And then:

```
Logger::set_target_file('error.log');
```

Using the `self::$file` attribute in `fopen` will cause the code to look for the absolute path, instead of relying on the current directory.

Comment: Can you explain the reason behind changing the current directory?

Comment: I have no idea why this happens. I just stumbled upon the same issue a while back and assumed it was a misbehavior/bug. I don't even know if it happens under linux.